# Pattern para HTML notas

Tags: html5, regex, validación, input

tengo un problema actualmente quiero hacer un pattern que admita numeros decimales como
(4,11) (4,9) (4) actualmente estoy manejando esto (\d(\.\d{1,2})?) en el pattern pero este parametro me admite son puntos y no comas lo que quiero es al contrario que me permita comas y no puntos.

Muchas gracias

Comment: y probaste reemplazando `\.` en el regex por `,`???

Comment: Si pero no funciono.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta mostrando el código html exacto y un ejemplo en el que no funcione, ya que se puede reemplazar por una coma y es la sintaxis correcta.

Answer (score 1):

- Solamente números:

```
^\d+$
```

- Solamente números de hasta 5 cifras:

```
^\d{1,5}$
```

- Números.
- Números decimales donde el separador sea la coma solamente, no un punto (opcional):

```
^\d+(,\d+)?$
```

- Mismo caso que el anterior solo que además de la coma, se podría usar como separador decimal también el punto.

```
^\d+([,.]\d+)?$
```

- Mismo caso que el anterior pero en el caso de los decimales permitir entre uno y dos dígitos de decimales:

```
^\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?$
```

**Explicación**:

1. `\d` : Match cualquier dígito del 0 al 9. Equivalente a [0-9]
2. `+` : Cuantificador. Match cuando haya coincidencia de 1 o más repeticiones. Por ejemplo `\d+` equivale a cualquier número (1) o varios números (154231).
3. `{}` : Cuantificador. Match cuando se cumple la condición. Por ejemplo `{1,3}` hace match cuando encuentra cierta condición de 1 a 3 veces. `\d{1,3}` Match con cualquier dato de ejemplo donde haya de 1 a 3 datos numéricos, por ejemplo: 1, 12, 123.
4. () : Capturar subgrupos. Por ejemplo al aplicar: `\d{1,3}(,\d+)` a 123,123 va a capturar el grupo completo 123,123 y un primer subgrupo ,123
5. [] : Match de un solo caracter, por ejemplo `\d[,.]\d`, va a hacer match a un digito numérico, que luego posea o una coma o un punto y finalmente un dígito numérico.
6. ? : Expresión precedida opcional.

Espero ayudarte.

Comment: ^\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?$ gracias por el aporte me funcionó perfectamente

Comment: Si te ha servido de ayuda podrías marcar la respuesta como válida. Saludos.